# Time stamp is not being written to Firebase database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I want to write a time stamp to the Firebase database so that I can later set what items can and can not be read from the Firebase database according to the time set. In my application I have a timpicker which the user uses to set the time, after which the set time is attached to the current date as shown below

```
 Calendar c=Calendar.getInstance();
  SimpleDateFormat df=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
   String dateToday=df.format(c.getTime());
 dateandtime=dateToday+time;
```

After which I convert dateandtime into a timestamp using the method below

```
try {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.SSS");
Date parsedDate=dateFormat.parse(dateandtime);
 timestamp=new Timestamp(parsedDate.getTime());
}catch (Exception e){}
```

My class called Travel details for writing  to the database is like this

```
  ...... 
   private Timestamp pickuptime;
   public Timestamp getPickuptime(){
   return pickuptime;}
    public void setPickuptime(Timestamp pickuptime){
     this.pickuptime=pickuptime;
```

}
And this is how I write the time to the database  in my main activity

```
  Timestamp timestamp;
  ............. 
  d.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
             TravelDetails travelDetails=new TravelDetails() ;
              travelDetails.setPickuptime(timestamp);

                myRef.child(userID).push().setValue( 
                 travelDetails);
                  Ali.push().setValue(travelDetails);
```

Instead of writing  the time stamp to the database everything else from travel details class is written to the Firebase database except the time stamp. Kindly render assistance.

Comment: `Timestamp timestamp;  
  TravelDetails travelDetails=new TravelDetails;  
   travelDetails.setPickuptime(timestamp);` is this part exactly like this in your code? because it seems you didn't initialize timestamp...

Comment: No it isn't sorry, the part for travel details is in on create while Timestamp and timestamp is above on create

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Realtime Database doesn't support writing Timestamp type values.  It looks like you might be trying to use a Cloud Firestore Timestamp with Realtime Database.  It doesn't work that way - they are different database systems.  Timestamp objects can only be used with Cloud Firestore documents.

If you want to record a point in time with Realtime Database, you typically just use a number value for that.

Comment: Would if I wrote it as a number, would I still be able to achieve my desired result of being able to set an expiry date to it. So I should make the timestamp an integer?

Comment: That's what I said - you typically use a number.